# How to use combineLatest and mergeMap for multiple subscribtions?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm still learning rxjs and I've a trouble with using multiple subscriptions. I need to get id from response to add a photos to product.

```
    create(product) {
     this.api.createProduct(product).subscribe(product => {
       product.photos.forEach(photo => {
         photo.productId = product.id;
         this.api.addPhoto(photo).subscribe();
      });
    });
```

This is my working solution, but I know it's wrong and I should use mergeMap and combineLatest, but I don't know how.

Update 1

My solution

```
create(productForm) {
  this.api.createProduct(productForm).pipe(
    mergeMap(photo => {
      return combineLatest([
        productForm.photos.map(photo => {
          this.api.addPhoto({...photo, productId: product.id})//.subscribe()
          })
        ]);
   ).subscribe();
}
```

I can't add photos in current solution. Only when I added subscribe to addPhoto it worked.

Update 2

My solution

```
create(productForm) {
  this.api.createProduct(productForm).pipe(
    mergeMap(photo => {
      const photos = [];
      productForm.photos.map(photo => {
        photos.push(this.api.addPhoto({...photo, productId: product.id}));
      });
      return combineLatest([...photos]);
   })
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Now it's working properly.

Comment: I did not get your issue, what do you really want to achieve? Can you please describe your primary goal in detail?

Comment: I wanted to get rid off nested subscribtion.

Comment: combineLatest has different purpose, you need `from` or `forkJoin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to you build a single pipe that does everything. Then once you need it - just subscribe once.

Also not clear why in your forEach there'are `comment` and `photo`, is it misspelled?

Anyway, your sequence could look like that:

```js
const flow$ = this.api.createProduct(product).pipe(
  mergeMap(product => {
    const sequence = [];
    product.photos.forEach(photo =>
      sequence.push(this.api.addPhoto({...photo, productId: product.id)),
    );
    return forkJoin(...sequence); // <- once product has been created it adds its photos.
  }),
);

// then somewhere
flow$.subscribe(); // <- makes the whole pipe active.
```

or you can have an Observable for photos and integrate it with the flow.

```js
const addPhotos =(product) => product.photos.map(photo => api.addPhoto({...photo, productId: product.id));

cont flow$ = api.createProduct(product).pipe(
  map(addPhotos),
  mergeMap(o$ => forkJoin(...o$)),
);
```

Comment: It was misspelled.

Comment: Ah, good, I've updated the code sample. The main goal of rx is to build data streams. Once you write one, just try to create a single pipe. It is fine also to mix pipes. I'll add code sample too.